# Ubuntu one: How to delete photos from cloud?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I have configured my android to auto-upload photos to the U1 cloud. Which is usefull in case I lose the phone.

However from time to time I want to clean out the junk photos. 
If I go to https://one.ubuntu.com/photos there doesn't seem to be any way to delete photos.
If I go to the https://one.ubuntu.com/files area and then the folder that the photos are in, I encounter the following problem:

```
Too many files or folders in this folder to display, only displaying 1000 entries.
```

So I can't figure out how to delete photos. 
Also if a file is deleted from the cloud will it be deleted from the sync'd devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Ubuntu One Files` application on Android to delete your files from the server, as well. Simply do a long press on the file in the list, and choose `Delete`.

However, the Android application doesn't do synchronization yet. You can manually upload or download files (or use the auto-upload feature for photos), but it will not keep them in sync, if they have changed. However, deleting files from the cloud will result in them being deleted on other devices with clients which do synchronization, such as on Ubuntu, Windows, or OS X.